# In my code below Yes/No statement is not functioning properly,

Tags: java

Issue I have is with yes/no statement, if I enter "no" it will continue instead to exit the program.
Please if someone can give me tip where issue is?

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGame {
    private static final int DO_NOT_PLAY_AGAIN = 0;

```
private final Scanner mScanner;
private final Random mRandom;
private String mUserName;
private int mCorrectAnswer;
private int mPlayAgainInput;
private String mAnswer;

public NumberGame() {
    mScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    mRandom = new Random();
}


public void run() {
    displayWelcomeMessage();
    getUserName();
    greetUser();
    getAnswer();


    do {
        intNumberGuessGame();
    } while (mPlayAgainInput != DO_NOT_PLAY_AGAIN);

    sayGoodbye();
}
  private void getAnswer(){
       System.out.println("Would you lioke to play a game enter yes to play or no to exit a game");
        mAnswer = mScanner.nextLine();
        if (mAnswer.equals("no")) 
        System.out.println("Maybe next time");
        sayGoodbye();
  }



private void displayWelcomeMessage() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game!");
    System.out.println("To play this game you have to"
                       + " guess a number and enter upon prompt or you can"
                       + " enter 0 to quit the game.");
}

private void getUserName() {
    System.out.println("Enter your user name: ");
    mUserName = mScanner.nextLine();
}

private void greetUser() {
    System.out.println("Let's play a game, " + mUserName + ".");
}

private void sayGoodbye() {
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing, " + mUserName + "!");
}

private void intNumberGuessGame() {
    // Get a random number between 1 - 100
    Random generator = new Random();
    mCorrectAnswer = mRandom.nextInt(100) + 1;
    int theirGuess = 0;
    int howManyTries = 0;
    while (theirGuess != mCorrectAnswer) {
        System.out.println("Guess my number: ");
        theirGuess = mScanner.nextInt();
        mCorrectAnswer = mRandom.nextInt(101) + 1;
        howManyTries++;

        System.out.println("Correct answer = " + mCorrectAnswer);

        if (theirGuess == mCorrectAnswer) {
            System.out.println("You guessed it! It only took you "
                    + howManyTries + " tries to get it right!");
            promptToPlayAgain();
            // They won the game, exit current loop
            break;
        } else if (theirGuess > mCorrectAnswer) {
            System.out.println("Your answer is too high.");
        } else if (theirGuess < mCorrectAnswer) {
            System.out.println("Your answer is too low.");
        }
    }
}

private void promptToPlayAgain() {
    System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (0 to quit): ");
    mPlayAgainInput = mScanner.nextInt();
}
```

}

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NumberGame().run();
}
}
```

Comment: Your sentinel is zero, based on `mPlayAgainInput = mScanner.nextInt();`.  Why are you assuming if it scans in "no" that it will exit the game?

Comment: this is part where I have problem, private void getAnswer(){
       System.out.println("Would you lioke to play a game enter yes to play or no to exit a game");
        mAnswer = mScanner.nextLine();
        if (mAnswer.equals("no")) 
        System.out.println("Maybe next time");
        sayGoodbye();
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems a little bit messy right now. I would advise you to redesign your code a little bit. Your problem lies in how `getAnswer()` function is designed - it prompts for answer, but does not use it. Change this function so it can return a boolean value:

```
private boolean getAnswer()
{
   System.out.println("Would you lioke to play a game enter yes to play or no to exit a game");
    mAnswer = mScanner.nextLine();

    if (mAnswer.equals("no"))
    {
        System.out.println("Maybe next time");
        sayGoodbye();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Use this result in `run()` to check if game should be started at all:

```
public void run()
{
    displayWelcomeMessage();
    getUserName();
    greetUser();

    if(getAnswer()) //User wants to play!
    {
        do
        {
            intNumberGuessGame();
        } while (mPlayAgainInput != DO_NOT_PLAY_AGAIN);

        sayGoodbye();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you're checking if mAnswer is equal to "no", you're only printing one string and you always execute the sayGoodbye because you're missing braces. It should be:

```
if (mAnswer.equals("no")) {
    System.out.println("Maybe next time");
    sayGoodbye();
}
```

Second of all, if you want the yes/no question to decide whether or not you continue playing, you will need to either check

```
do {
    intNumberGuessGame();
} while (mPlayAgainInput != DO_NOT_PLAY_AGAIN || !mAnswer.equals("no"));
```

or set the mPlayAgainInput value to 0 in the getAnswer() function, precisely in the braces i pointed out earlier. If you choose this option, you should change to do-while block to a regular while block.

Answer (score 0):

Because when the user inputs "no" you simply print a message and never actually tell the program to exit.

You can adjust it in many different ways, for example change the `getAnswer` method to:

```
    private int getAnswer() {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play a game? Enter yes to play or no to exit a game");
        mAnswer = mScanner.nextLine();
        if (mAnswer.equals("no")) {
            System.out.println("Maybe next time");
            return DO_NOT_PLAY_AGAIN;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

And your `run` method to:

```
    public void run() {
        displayWelcomeMessage();
        getUserName();
        greetUser();
        mPlayAgainInput = getAnswer();


        while (mPlayAgainInput != DO_NOT_PLAY_AGAIN) {
            intNumberGuessGame();
        }

        sayGoodbye();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ivaylo Toskov.

Comment: @DKCroat Don't just go away once someone helps you.  Show thanks by upvoting Answers and accepting the best answer using the check mark.

Comment: I certainly will do @BLaZuRE. I do apologize it's first time I am using this site. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: Thank you all for giving me your inputs on my question.